# Foreign key referencing composite table

Tags: sql-server, triggers, view, foreign-keys

I've got a table structure I'm not really certain of how to create the best way.

Basically I have two tables, tblSystemItems and tblClientItems. I have a third table that has a column that references an 'Item'. The problem is, this column needs to reference either a system item or a client item - it does not matter which. System items have keys in the 1..2^31 range while client items have keys in the range -1..-2^31, thus there will never be any collisions.

Whenever I query the items, I'm doing it through a view that does a UNION ALL between the contents of the two tables.

Thus, optimally, I'd like to make a foreign key reference the result of the view, since the view will always be the union of the two tables - while still keeping IDs unique. But I can't do this as I can't reference a view.

Now, I can just drop the foreign key, and all is well. However, I'd really like to have some referential checking and cascading delete/set null functionality. Is there any way to do this, besides triggers?

Comment: For the love of Pete, STOP PREFIXING TABLE NAMES WITH "TBL". It's gross and disgusting and horrifying all at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the late answer, I've been struck with a serious case of weekenditis.

As for utilizing a third table to include PKs from both client and system tables - I don't like that as that just overly complicates synchronization and still requires my app to know of the third table.

Another issue that has arisen is that I have a third table that needs to reference an item - either system or client, it doesn't matter. Having the tables separated basically means I need to have two columns, a ClientItemID and a SystemItemID, each having a constraint for each of their tables with nullability - rather ugly.

I ended up choosing a different solution. The whole issue was with easily synchronizing new system items into the tables without messing with client items, avoiding collisions and so forth.

I ended up creating just a single table, Items. Items has a bit column named "SystemItem" that defines, well, the obvious. In my development / system database, I've got the PK as an int identity(1,1). After the table has been created in the client database, the identity key is changed to (-1,-1). That means client items go in the negative while system items go in the positive.

For synchronizations I basically ignore anything with (SystemItem = 1) while synchronizing the rest using IDENTITY INSERT ON. Thus I'm able to synchronize while completely ignoring client items and avoiding collisions. I'm also able to reference just one "Items" table which covers both client and system items. The only thing to keep in mind is to fix the standard clustered key so it's descending to avoid all kinds of page restructuring when the client inserts new items (client updates vs system updates is like 99%/1%).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a table say tblItems that simply store all the primary keys of the two tables. Inserting items would require two steps to ensure that when an item is entered into the tblSystemItems table that the PK is entered into the tblItems table.

The third table then has a FK to tblItems. In a way tblItems is a parent of the other two items tables. To query for an Item it would be necessary to create a JOIN between tblItems, tblSystemItems and tblClientItems.

[EDIT-for comment below] If the tblSystemItems and tblClientItems control their own PK then you can still let them. You would probably insert into tblSystemItems first then insert into tblItems. When you implement an inheritance structure using a tool like Hibernate you end up with something like this.

Comment: But then I'll have a hassle synchronizing the PK containing tblItems table when I push changes to the tblSystemItems table. Optimally I'd like the tblSystemItems table to work completely independent of the client items.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique id (db generated - sequence, autoinc, etc) for the table that references items, and create two additional columns (**tblSystemItemsFK** and **tblClientItemsFk**) where you reference the system items and client items respectively - *some* databases allows you to have a foreign key that is *nullable*.

If you're using an ORM you can even easily distinguish client items and system items (this way you don't need to negative identifiers to prevent ID overlap) based on column information only.

With a little more bakcground/context it is probably easier to determine an optimal solution.

Comment: Only *some* databases allow you to have null foreign keys?  Do only *some* databases allow you to do OUTER JOINs, too?

Answer (score 0):

Add a table called Items with a PK ItemiD, And a single column called ItemType = "System" or "Client" then have ClientItems table PK (named ClientItemId) and SystemItems PK (named SystemItemId) both also be FKs to Items.ItemId, (These relationships are zero to one relationships (0-1)

Then in your third table that references an item, just have it's FK constraint reference the itemId in this extra (Items) table...

If you are using stored procedures to implement inserts, just have the stored proc that inserts items insert a new record into the Items table first, and then, using the auto-generated PK value in that table insert the actual data record into either SystemItems or ClientItems (depending on which it is)  as part of the same stored proc call, using the auto-generated (identity) value that the system inserted into the Items table ItemId column.

This is called "SubClassing"

Answer (score 0):

I've been puzzling over your table design. I'm not certain that it is right. I realise that the third table may just be providing detail information, but I can't help thinking that the primary key is actually the one in your ITEM table and the FOREIGN keys are the ones in your system and client item tables. You'd then just need to do right outer joins from Item to the system and client item tables, and all constraints would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation in a database I'm using.  I have a "candidate key" on each table that I call EntityID.  Then, if there's a table that needs to refer to items in more than one of the other tables, I use EntityID to refer to that row.  I do have an Entity table to cross reference everything (so that EntityID is the primary key of the Entity table, and all other EntityID's are FKs), but I don't find myself using the Entity table very often.